# Swift Compiler error: 'Double' is not convertible to CGFloat

Tags: ios, c, xcode, swift

I just began learning Swift. I created a game project and a template came up. I have not done anything to the code whatsoever. I tried to run the project but a compiler error popped up.

I'm going off a tutorial so it could be something wrong with my environment or the book is already outdated.

Swift Compiler error: 'Double' is not convertible to CGFloat

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
        myLabel.text = "Hello, World!";
        myLabel.fontSize = 65;
        myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

        self.addChild(myLabel)
    }

    override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        /* Called when a mouse click occurs */

        let location = theEvent.locationInNode(self)

        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")
        sprite.position = location;
        sprite.setScale(0.5)

        let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(M_PI, duration:1)
        sprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))

        self.addChild(sprite)
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

The error occurs in `let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(M_PI, duration:1)`

Here is a screenshot of the project settings
[image]

Comment: Which line does the error appear on? Click on the error on the left in the screenshot you posted and it'll take you to the line with the error.

Comment: line 23: let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(M_PI, duration:1)

Comment: This question will be outdated in [Swift 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130215/swift-double-is-not-convertable-to-cgfloat/68040711#68040711).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can convert it with `CGFloat(M_PI)`.

For example the following code should work in your case (note the use of `CGFloat`)

```
let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration:1)
```

Comment: Why there is no implicit casting (in terms of design decision of a language)? In Java, I can pass in `Integer` (wrapper) where `int` (underlying type) is expected. This should be harmless since Swift does not need to be compatible with C.

Comment: Swift is very big on preventing accidents. If you weren't aware you were casting you might be surprised further down the line.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare pi like this in your code : `let π = CGFloat(M_PI)` and then use `let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(π, duration:1)`

If you are going to use π a lot, it's way more simple.

You can type π with the shortcut alt+p

Answer (score -2):

The old M_PI was a Double, but the function did expect a CGFloat. A cast would be the solution.

```
let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration:1)
```

With respect to Swift 5 it would be now:

```
let action = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: .pi, duration:1)
```

No need to cast anymore

Comment: what does "add a cast" mean? care to elaborate? might be helpful for others

Comment: Cast: aDouble as CGFloat

Comment: If you are running on a 64 bit iOS, `Double` *still* isn't convertible to `CGFloat` without calling the `CGFloat` constructor...